# Does casting and assignment really strip away any extra precision of floats?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am reading through the [new C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith2) and I see that even if `x == y` for `double x, y;` then it is possible for:

```
std::cos(x) == std::cos(y)
```

to evaluate to `false`. This is because the machine can have a processor which supports extended precision, such that one part of the `==` is a 64 bit number while the other one is an 80 bit number.

However, the next example seems to be incorrect:

```
void foo(double x, double y)
{
  double cos_x = cos(x);
  double cos_y = cos(y);
  // the behavior might depend on what's in here
  if (cos_x != cos_y) {
    std::cout << "Huh?!?\n";  // You might end up here when x == y!!
  }
}
```

As far as I [read on en.cppreference.com here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD):

> Cast and assignment strip away any extraneous range and precision:
>   this models the action of storing a value from an extended-precision
>   FPU register into a standard-sized memory location.

Hence, assigning:

```
double cos_x = cos(x);
double cos_y = cos(y);
```

should trim away any extra precision and make the program perfectly predictable.

So, who is right? The C++ FAQ, or the en.cppreference.com?

Comment: In your example, sure, the extra precision of the result of `cos(v)` may be stripped away. That doesn't mean the extra precision of `v` in `cos(v)` doesn't change that result. Generally, floating-point operations are all platform-specific, so it's up to your compiler to have flags and documentation of what floating-point behavior will be. For example, most compilers will let you say "I want strict 32-bit floating-point semantics", so none of this stuff applies.

Comment: Elaborating on @GManNickG comment, for instance GCC has the options `-ffloat-store` and `-fexcess-precision=` to choose the desired behavior.

Comment: BTW: I find the language-lawyer tag weird here. The C++ standard isn't really the reference document for floating point, and I doubt anybody *enjoys* going through IEEE/Intel specifications. Again, it basically boils down to it's "implementation/hardware". But just generally the premise of the question relies on heresay from two different non-normative sources, so what are we supposed to be lawyering here?

Answer (score 3):

Neither the ISOCPP FAQ or cppreference are authoritative sources. cppreference is essentially the equivalent of wikipedia: it contains good information, but anybody can add anything without sources you have to read it with a grain of salt. Are the following three statements true:

> Did you catch that? Your particular installation might store the result of one of the cos() calls out into RAM, truncating it in the process, then later compare that truncated value with the untruncated result of the second cos() call. Depending on lots of details, those two values might not be equal.
>
> This is because the machine can have a processor which supports extended precision, such that one part of the `==` is a 64 bit number while the other one is an 80 bit number.
>
> Cast and assignment strip away any extraneous range and precision: this models the action of storing a value from an extended-precision FPU register into a standard-sized memory location.

Maybe. It depends on the platform, your compiler, the compiler options, or any number of things. Realistically, the above statements only hold true for GCC in 32-bit mode, which defaults to the legacy x87 FPU (where everything is 80-bits internally) and rounded down to 64-bit when storing in memory. 64-bit uses SSE so double temporaries are always 64-bit. You *can* force SSE with `mfpmath=sse` and `-msse2`. Either way, the assembly might look something like this:

```
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm1
    call    cos
    movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
    movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp], xmm0
    movapd  xmm0, xmm1
    call    cos
    movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rsp]
    ucomisd xmm2, xmm0
```

As you can see there is no truncation of any sort nor 80-bit registers used  here.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I removed the language lawyer tag. However, I would be really interested what the C++ standard has to say about the issue. I know that it does not specify much about the floating point arithmetic, but it specifies some important things.

Answer (score 1):

I wish that assignment or casting would toss away the extra precision. I have worked with "clever" compilers for which this does not happen. Many do, but if you want truly machine-independent code, you need do extra work.

You can force the compiler to always use the value in memory with the expected precision by declaring the variable with the "volatile" keyword.

Some compilers pass parameters in registers rather than on the stack. For these compilers, it could be that *x* or *y* could have unintended extra precision. To be totally safe, you could do

```
volatile double  db_x = x,          db_y = y;
volatile double cos_x = cos(db_x), cos_y = cos(db_y);
if (cos_x != cos_y)...
```